# Parsing JSON array using Autobean

Tags: java, json, gwt, autobean

I have a JSON which I'd like to parse using [Autobean](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/AutoBean). I'm getting NullPointerException in the for loop, probably persons.getPersons()

```
AppAutoBeanFactory factory = GWT.create(AppAutoBeanFactory.class);
    AutoBean<PersonsWrapper> bean =AutoBeanCodex.decode(factory, PersonsWrapper.class, "{\"persons\": " + strResponse + "}");
    IPersons persons = bean.as().getPersons();


        for (IPerson person : persons.getPersons()) {
            ...
        }
```

my AppAutoBeanFactory looks like this:

```
 interface AppAutoBeanFactory extends AutoBeanFactory {

   AutoBean<IPerson> person();
   AutoBean<IPersons> ipersons();
   AutoBean<PersonsWrapper> persons();


}
```

The JSON (variable strResponse) looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "name":"John",
    "surname":"Blue",
    "records":[10.5, 12.5, 18.6]
  },
  {
    "name":"Steven",
    "surname":"Green",
    "records":[11.5, 15.5, 14.6]
   }
]
```

I've made these interfaces:

```
public interface PersonsWrapper {
 IPersons getPersons();
}

public interface IPersons {

    void setPersons(List<IPerson> persons);
    List<IPerson> getPersons();

}

public interface IPerson {

  String getName();
  void setName(String name); 
  String getSurname();
  void setSurname(String surname);
}
```

How can I make it work? And how to add the records array to IPerson?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you did it, you're expecting the JSON to have `{"persons:{"persons":[…]}}`: the outer object is a `PersonsWrapper` whose `persons` property is a `IPersons`, whose `persons` property is a `List<IPerson>`.

Try ditching `PersonsWrapper` and just using `IPersons` instead:

```
IPersons bean =AutoBeanCodex.decode(factory, IPersons.class, "{\"persons\": " + strResponse + "}").as();

for (IPerson person : bean.getPersons()) {
    ...
}
```